# cordova my height body got shrink after keyboard pop up

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm struggling the whole week to try to solve the shrink problem with the keyboard. There was a plugin from 2015 but it's very hard deprecated and doesn't work anymore.

My problem is, I have a navbar in the top of the body, position:absolute or fixed, I've tried both. Non of them worked.

`<navbar style="position:absolute; top:0; margin:0;" />`

nothing worked. When the keyboard pops up, the navbar get a few pixels upside and doesn't go back anymore.

I didn't find a recently plugin that works like his old predecessor (https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard)

Someone else struggled with this and work it out?

Comment: where is your code? and what is `<navbar>`? it's not defined in HTML standard.

Comment: it happened with any code in Cordova. navbar element is a element in the dom page only, doesn't have style definition in any place, only the style you're seeing inline. Anyway I think I got a solution, this is happening in all Cordova built apps that have bootstrap inside

Comment: oh yes I found a solution, I will post it later to help others